# Solve this nonhomegenous ode $y''+4y = \cos(2x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the given nonhomogenous linear ODE by variation of parameters or undetermined coefficients $y'' + 4y = \cos(2x)$.

A general solution is $y_1 = \cos(2x), y_2 = \sin(2x)$, and the Wronksin determinant is equal to 2.

Plugging this into the equation for the method of variation of parameters, I get
$$-\cos(2x)\int\frac{\sin(2x)\cos(2x)}{2}dx + \sin(2x)\int\frac{\cos^2(2x)}{2}dx$$

The integrals cancel out to $0$. How can I approach this correctly with the method proposed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then by variation of parameters we have the particular solution is given by
$$y_p=\cos(2x)u_{1}+\sin(2x)u_{2}$$
where
$$u_{1}=-\frac{1}{2}\int \cos(2x)\sin(2x){\rm d}x=\frac{1}{16}\cos(4x)$$
and
$$u_{2}=\frac{1}{2}\int \cos(2x)\cos(2x){\rm d}x=\frac{x}{4}+\frac{\sin(4x)}{16}.$$

Simplify, we have the general solution

$$y=c_{1}\cos(2x)+c_{2}\sin(2x)+\frac{1}{4}x\sin(2x). $$

Comment: The answer to this exercise shows your missing $\frac{1}{8}\cos(2x)$ in the general solution

Answer (score 3):

As $2i$ is a simple root of the characteristic equation of the l.h.s., a particular solution of the non-homogeneous equation has the form
$$y_0(x)=Ax\cos 2x+Bx\sin 2x$$
whence
\begin{align}
y'_0(x)&=A\cos 2x-2Ax\sin 2x+B\sin 2x+2Bx\cos 2x \\
&= (A+2Bx)\cos 2x+(B-2Ax)\sin 2x,\\
y''_0(x)&=4(B-A)\cos 2x-4(A+Bx)\sin 2x.
\end{align}
Can you proceed?

Comment: Sure! I got $A = 0$ and $B = \frac{1}{4}$ plugging this into the complex roots $e^{0}(0\cos(2x) + \frac{1}{4}\sin(2x))$ this implies the general solution is $\frac{1}{4}\sin(2x)$?

Comment: No. You have to add to the particular solution (which b.t.w. is $\frac14\color{red} x \sin 2x)$ the general solution of the associated homogeneous equation. As for algebraic equations, the solutions of a non-homogeneous linear o.d.e.  are an affine space.

Comment: Ah ... I had a minutes moment of confusion but I've got it now! I think the variables used threw me off as I'm used to $y_h$ and $y_p$. Where $y_h = Ax\cos(2x) + Bx\sin(2x)$ and after finding $B = \frac{1}{4}$ we add the particular solution. Although, how did you get your general solution? In my book it only gives for the choice of $y_p(x)$ in an instance like this $K \cos(\omega x) + M \sin(\omega x)$?

Comment: @me.limes: The equation $y''+\omega^2y=0$ is standard, and it is a classical result that the vector space of its solutions have as a basis either two conjugate complex exponentials or $\cos\omega x$ and \sin\omega x$.

Comment: True, although how did we know to include an extra $x$ variable outside the sine and cosine functions?

Comment: It's something I learnt when I was a student: if the r.h.s. is $\mathrm e^{i\lambda x}$, and if $\lambda$ is a simple root of the characteristic equation, an obvious particular solution is $cx\mathrm e^{\lambda x}$. If it is a double root, the factor should be $cx^2$.

Comment: I'll take a note of this!

Answer (score 1):

Null space solution

$m^2 +4 =0$

$\implies m=\pm 2i$

Hence,  $ y_N = C_1 \sin 2x + C_2 \cos 2x$.

Since, $\cos2x$ already in null space solution, take particular integral as $$y_p =x(A \sin 2x +B \cos 2x) $$

Then, \begin{align}  y'_p &{=A \sin 2x +B \cos 2x +2x(A \cos 2x -B \sin 2x )}\\ ​\end{align}

$y''_p =4A \cos 2x -4B \sin 2x -4x(A\sin 2x + B \cos 2x )$

$$y''_p +4y'_p = \cos 2x$$

\begin{align} {4A\cos 2x -4B\sin 2x -4x(A\sin 2x + B\cos 2x )+4x(A \sin 2x +B \cos 2x) =\cos 2x } \end{align}

$4A\cos 2x -4B\sin 2x= \cos 2x$

$4A=1$ , $4B=0$

$A=1/4$ , $B=0$

Hence, $y_p = \frac {1}{4}{x\sin 2x }$

So, $$y_\text{complete} =y_N + y_p$$

$$y_\text{complete}=C_1\sin 2x + C_2\cos 2x +  \frac {1}{4}{x \sin 2x }$$

Answer (score 0):

$$y''+4y = \cos(2x)$$
Since $\cos (2x)$ is even you need $y_p$ to be even too, so you only need:
$$y_p=Ax \sin (2x)$$